# WooCommerce: Add content to archive with multiple filter attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add some SEO content to some of my archives.

For example:

I have a category called "**Sportcars**". 
It's easy to add some content thereby adding it to the category archive page.

But I also want some content on the archive where I filter by "**Sportcars**" (product category), "**Cabrio**" (attribute) and "**black**" (attribute).

The URL looks something like this:

> domain.com/products/**sportcars**/?filter_type=**cabrio**&filter_color=**black**

Is there any way to address such an archive?

I'm thinking about something to do with the URL parameters.
But I couldn't figure out a good solution.

Maybe there is a way to rewrite the URL to add some ID's for the category and the filters and use them to build a custom post type with a slug based on ID's.
I can then search for the post type and display. it's content.
But maybe the filters are in different orders sometimes!?

For example here's what I mean:

> domain.com/products/**100**/?filter_type=**200**&filter_color=**300**

Now the Custom Post Type slug is something like this (not visible in the frontend):

> /seo-content/**100**-**200**-**300**/

Is this possible? Or is there a better way?
I searched a lot and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to get the job done without messing with custom slugs and archives is to use a php if statement in your archive checking if the values posted is "cabrio" & "black" like this:

```
$filter_type = $_GET[filter_type];
$filter_color = $_GET[filter_color];
if ( (isset($filter_type) == 'cabrio') && (isset($filter_color) == 'black') ) 
{
//your content here
} else {
//your content here
}
```

Comment: That looks fine. I just need to manage the content somewhere. I think a CPT is fine for that. But you're right. I don't need that custom slug stuff ;-) And of course I have to build a long if/else statement. But I can live with that for now.

Comment: One last question: Do you know a solution to check if there is ANY active filter?

Comment: I added if isset to check if $_GET var has a value first, checking if any filter exists